# Detecting touch by user at any point of time

Tags: android

I have a child view in my parent view.
Now I am using animation to show child view for 10 sec and hide it after that.
I want to show the child view even after 10 sec only if user touches it while animating.
So how can I determine if the child view is touched by user or not?
Does android provide any API to determine if view is touched by user at any instance of time?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the "clickable" property to true and setOnClickListener(). like this:

```
exampleView.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //TODO
        }
    });
```

You can also use the setOnTouchListener for more information on the "click".

[Take a look here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html)

Comment: with ur code we can find what needs to be done after click. But I want find out while animating if click has happened or not. So I want something like this.. animationAPI(){ if(view.isTouched){ don't hide the clid view}}. So want to know if there exists something like isTouched or any other api which can help

Comment: You could just have a Boolean variable like isTouched and set it true in the onClick() method. I'm not sure if onClick() happens after the animation, but if it does, then you could use the [onTouch](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) method that lets you know if a gesture of any kind has happened in the bounds of the view.